# Slow startup after update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, black-screen-of-death

I recently had a windows update to v1703 (64bit), which I launched before going to bed and, overnight, my PC got the Black screen of death after the logging. Weird thing is, when I launch explorer.exe manually, it takes 5 or 10 mins before appearing.

I've still been able to use my computer (since it doesn't prevent windows to be opened) but it is still very problematic. The Safe mode works just fine.

Note that it happened overnight and that I didn't install any program the day before.

Things I've tried so far:

- Re-updated windows
- Regedit
- Uninstalling graphic drivers
- Unplugging any unnecessary accessory

Does someone have a solution ?

Comment: Try to reset system. Then install driver from device manager

Comment: Specify which update you installed precisely

Comment: @Ramhound It happened after I made the update to v1703, and also each time I try to update to v1709, it fails

Comment: Update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, turns out I had the update v1709 pending and was failing each time it launched itself, after some time it finally installed itself and I no longer have the black screen.
That was still a weird bug.